# How much do you have to stake to become a validator?

Tags: nearprotocol, nearprotocol-validator

Any command to do it? I just started staking and I think I don't have enough stake :( Any idea of how somebody could help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The minimum stake to become a validator depends in how much is staked on the system at the moment. Near uses [Thresholded Proof of Stake](https://medium.com/nearprotocol/thresholded-proof-of-stake-67b74e616a92), so you can say the minimum stake to become a validator is roughly the sum of the current stake divided by the number of seats (which is currently 100 for betanet/stakewars).

In particular to see the current seat price for the current epoch you can use near-shell:

`$> near validators current | grep "seat price"`

To see the estimate price for the next epoch you can use as suggested per previous answer:

`$> near validators next | grep "seat price"`

Answer (score 0):

near validators next | grep "seat price"